# What's the real limit on deployment slots?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits), there's a limit on deployment slots per App Service Plan, for example, for Standard is 5.

Is this limit for the whole Service Plan or is per Web Site in the Service Plan?
I ask this because I have a Service Plan S1 with more than 5 web sites and each web app has 1 deployment slot, and it seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deployment slot limit is per Web app not the whole App Service Plan. That's mean if you have 5 Web apps hosted in your S1 App service plan, each one of them can have up to 5 deployment slots.